# Desktop Folders are opened with dolphin file manager?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, dolphin

All my folder which is inside Desktop are opened with `Dolphin File Manager`. How to open those files with default `Nautilus File Manager`? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use Dolphin at all, you can remove it with

```
sudo apt-get purge dolphin -y
```

And it should prompt you for a new default program afterwards when you click the icon.

If you want to keep dolphin, and assuming you're using Ubuntu 18.04 (since you tagged gnome), you should be able to right click the icon, click properties -> open with, and select a new default application from there.

Comment: Ok so it did work. I'd to run `sudo apt autoremove`.